# Qualtrics - place an image using Javascript at the top of a question, or at least not at the very bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, qualtrics

I'm working on a survey where I am adding images via Javascript (I cannot add the images manually because there are hundreds of images based on different conditions).

I have done the following where I have a block with two separate questions, one blank question with Javascript to display the image, and then below the text of the question.

[image: Example survey flow]

However, when I preview the survey, the image **always** appears at the very bottom of the page, no matter how I reorder the blocks.

[image: Example survey preview]

Here is the Javascript I've written to display the image:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

function display_image(src, width, height) {
  var a = document.createElement("img");
  a.src = src;
  a.width = width;
  a.height = height;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
    
display_image('URL GOES HERE', 
         770, 
         385);

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/

});
```

Any ideas? I'm quite stuck.

Comment: You're appending the element to the body so of course it ends up at the bottom of the document.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks for the insight! I'm totally new to Javascript and plucked out the code for the image display from another Stackoverflow question—could you point me in the right direction of where I should be appending to instead?

Comment: We don’t know what element you want to add those child imgs to. When you know that do element.appendChild(a)